# Telnet Duplicate Data Wireshark Retransmissions Sever/Client Winsock

Tags: c++, network-programming, winsock, wireshark

I’m using Wireshark to monitor telnet server/client transmissions. Occasionally the server's incoming  text buffer  pulls in multiple  instances of the same incoming data string like so:

*1890000000000900000000A00000000B000000000064/\r*1890000000000900000000A00000000B000000000064/\r*1890000000000900000000A00000000B000000000064/\r*1890000000000900000000A00000000B000000000064/\r

When this happens Wireshark says they are retransmissions.  TCP wouldn't be responsible for the duplicated data would it? Should I focus more on the client code as the source of duplication?

I might add that this application is communicating over 2.4ghz WiFi with 23 access points. It is a very congested network.

Answer (score 1):

Does Wireshark show any unusually colored entries just before the perceived re-transmission? If wireshark says the packet is a re-transmission, you can assume the server (via TCP) is re-sending it. You can verify this if may appear the client does not send an ACK for that packet initially, or subsequently.

Comment: No unusual colors. Let me ask you this. If the client sends one data string is it possible - through the magic of TCP - for the server to receive duplicated strings from that one transmission if the network is noisy or has outages?

Comment: TCP will automatically retry. So, if the server was expecting data, and doesn't get it, it will re-request it. And yes, it has the possibility to receive dupes... but the TCP stack will generally know it was a dup (and send a message out saying it was a dup). It can either ignore it, or tear the connection down at this point (where you'd need to recconet possibly).